# Unable to Click Button Using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-applications, automation

I'm new to selenium and I came across a webpage where I wanted to click a button which is nested inside with other tags,

**HTML**

```html
<div ng-show="hasAuthenticated &amp;&amp; !accessingInEU" class="account-buttons ng-isolate-scope signed-in" ng-class="{ 'signed-in': loggedIn }" style="">
   <!-- ngIf: loggedIn -->
   <authenticated-button ng-if="loggedIn" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" style="">
      <icon-button icon-class="authenticated icon-account-male" on-click="authenticatedButtonCtrl.showAccountSettings()" class="ng-isolate-scope">
         <button class="icon-container icon-button ng-binding" ng-click="onClick()" tabindex="0">
            <span aria-hidden="true" ng-class="iconClass" class="authenticated icon-account-male" />
         </button>
      </icon-button>
   </authenticated-button>
</div>
```

These are the code snippets which I've tried,

**Sample Codes Used**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
boolean invisiable = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
        .invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".icon-container.icon-button.ng-binding")));
if (invisiable) {
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".icon-container.icon-button.ng-binding"));
    ele.click();
}
```

When I tried the above code, The Below Exception arises

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

I have also tried the below code using XPath, Still, I cannot able to click it.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//authenticated-button//icon-button//button[contains(@class,'icon-container icon-button ng-binding')]")).click();
```

Can Someone guide me for solving this problem?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Try to click on icon-button instead of button and tell me if it works.

Comment: I have tried that too. But Still the same problem persists..

Comment: Can you give me the URL of the page so i can test it or do you want to keep it private?

Comment: It is called "Mapquest.com"...After you logged in, I'm trying to click the user icon

Comment: I logged in but i can't see the user icon you are talking of...

Answer (score 0):

You are waiting for the element to be invisible and then trying to click on it. It is not interactable at this moment.

Try instead waiting for the element to be clickable and then clicking it:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions
        .elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(".icon-container.icon-button.ng-binding"))).click();
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and it results in TimeOutException..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
```

Instead of Selenium's click() method

If it doesn't work try using the Action class

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(ele).click().perform();
```

If it doesn't works too then we'll look deeper into the element in question.